# Windows Media Player Changes not reflected in File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, mp3, windows-media-player, metadata

Basically When I update song info such as artist, title etc in windows media player, the changes are not made to the mp3 file itself.

I have just spent hours ensuring the songs have the correct info only to realize that the changes aren't being made to the songs themselves. The info displays correctly in windows media player.

I used A program called tuneUp to help update the info but I still had to manually enter a lot of info.

Yes I have tried refreshing/Rebooting.

Is there a way I can tell windows media player to change the metadata in the mp3 file itself?

**In the screenshot I am viewing the properties of the same file in windows media player and windows explorer after updating the info**
[image: In the screenshot I am viewing the properties of the same file in windows media player and windows explorer after updating the info]

Comment: OK, I’ll ask the obvious questions: Have you tried refreshing your view in Windows Explorer?  Logging out and in again?  Rebooting?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 12):

Steps to update apply media information from windows media player to files.

1. Tools(Ctrl+M)->Options->Library-> tick "write media information changes to files"
2. Update media information manually by write click and edit or write click on file and click find media information.
3. to immediately update media information to file click Tools->Apply media information changes. ( else Media information will be automatically written after some interval of time anyways)

[image: write media information changes to files]

Comment: Thank you.  This must be something new.  (Or at least the setting got flipped recently by an update.)  I've been managing my media library with WMP for many, many years and have never encountered this before now.  I was stumped.

Comment: glad I was helpful. I too found it recently. Not sure if it was present earlier.

Comment: This does not work as of today.  No error, but information is not applied to files.  I have an album for which there is no online data, so it shows up as Unknown Artist.  After editing the album and track info I tried the above but it does not get applied to the folder and files in the library.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when you change the info of a song in the library, WMP doesn't immediately write the change to the corresponding music file, but waits a while and then does this quietly in the background. You can use `Tools` -
 `Apply media information changes` to force WMP to write all changes to file immediately (press Ctrl+M if you don't see the Tools menu). Do you see the changes reflected in the files themselves after using this command?

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't work for me, I also tried un-ticking update media information from the internet and made sure the folders were not set to read only. I ended up downloading Itunes which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was some files were ONLY READ. I changed that attribute, then all changes were made.